# CiviEvent + SearchKit = number of free slots in an event?

Tags: civievent, searchkit

How to create a SearchKit result of CiviEvent events, where the result contains the number of free slots left in the event?

**What I have:**

- My test setup is newest WP 6.3.2 and newest CiviCRM 5.66.0.
- CiviEvent: several events, with a max no. of participants, and some registrations on those events.
- SearchKit: a search that gives me open events in the next 2 weeks.
  The result presents no actions, no sorting, just a static table listing.
- Form Builder: a form to hold the results from the search.
- WordPress: a page that contains the shortcode with my search.

**What I want:**

- The form content should contain a column with the number of remaining available slots, to answer a question like "can I register 4 more people to this, or are there not enough free spaces left?
- How do I build a search query that can take the max no. of participants and then subtract the number of already-registered from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature has been [recently added to SearchKit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/27839) and will be part of the upcoming 5.68 release.

Comment: Thank you - good to hear! <3 As far as I can tell, 5.68 is released early Dec'23, correct?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Just to confirm: I am now using this new field "event.remaining_participants" and it's fine!